# How do I properly do a Google oauth2 javascript workflow on mobile?

Tags: javascript, mobile, oauth-2.0

I am building a simple mobile webapp that authenticates itself against Google's oauth2 service using the javascript api. Whereas on the desktop it works fine, the mobile version sticks in the last step of the workflow. It does not return to the main page, but stays on the following url:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?immediate=false&response_type=token&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me&redirect_uri=postmessage&proxy=oauth2relay1692997977&state=455491569&origin=[http://mydomain.com]&client_id=[myclientid]&authuser=0&hl=nl&from_login=1&as=fb5f6593cf79e46&pli=1
```

I used the following sample [code](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/source/browse/samples/authSample.html)

Tested it on Windows Phone 7.5's IE9.

What do I need to do to fix this, and to let the workflow end up in the main page?

Answer (score 0):

The sample code you provided is designed for auth flow in popup window on desktop browsers. It does not work correctly on mobile browsers. I would suggest you use a library that does the auth flow using redirect.